# Different resolutions in browsers and media queries

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, width

Hello I have got a problem.

In CSS I have got :

```
@media(max-width: 1000px){  
    body{  
        background-color:red;  
    }
}
```

and in FireFox background changed on 1013px width and in Chrome on 1018px

`$(window).width()` in jquery in FireFox is 983px, Chrome  979px.

What is going on with it? I use bootstrap.css

Thanks!

Comment: it's probably the difference between the scrollbar size! nevermind it and use the numbers as you wish! (i.e. 1000px will work for all the browsers)

Comment: You probably want [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerWidth) instead

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the browser handles scrollbars where the viewport is concerned. Chrome and Safari (Webkit) exclude the scrollbar dimensions. Firefox, Opera and IE include the scrollbar dimensions.

According to [W3C Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width)

> The ‘width’ media feature describes the width of the targeted display area of the output device. For continuous media, this is the width of the viewport (as described by CSS2, section 9.1.1 [CSS21]) ***including the size of a rendered scroll bar (if any)***. For paged media, this is the width of the page box (as described by CSS2, section 13.2 [CSS21]).

Essentially Webkit browsers handle this incorrectly.